# Error viewing API Manager Statistics using WSO2 DAS

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I'm attempting to use *AM 1.9.1* and Store statistics in *DAS 3.0.0*. I'm using a mysql database to house my *WSO2AM_STATS_DB* instance.

Data is being stored successfully in the database. I have records indicating that attempts were throttled out and requests were made successfully. Unfortunately, when I attempt to view any of the statistics in either the store or the publisher application, the logs show this error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'TempTable.apiPublisher' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to resolve this?

Comment: Is this error message appear in DAS log or APIM log? Could you check whether data published or not into DAS by viewing in cassandra explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by removing the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` from the configuration for MySQL.